# Google App Engine 1.7.5 to 1.8.9 "NoSuchMethodError"?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, nosuchmethoderror

I've been working on a java project that uses Google App Engine 1.7.5 and i was supposed to update it to 1.8.9.
The project still runs "fine" after the update, but now i'm getting some errors on the unit tests like this one:

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$Query.makeImmutable()V*

on this line of the unit test code:

`root = ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("name", "root").first().safeGet()`;

Does anybody know anything about this?
Thanks for any help you can provide me on this case.

Comment: Do you know which version of Objectify you are using?  The `safeGet()` method has been deprecated in favour of `safe()`, which may help others more knowledgeable than me answer the question.

Comment: I'm using Objectify 4.0b1, when i updated it to 4.0b3 i got several errors with my @Embed tags on fields saying "@Embed is disallowed on this location"

Comment: I Corrected the @Embed error, but i'm still getting the NoSuchMethodError with Objectify 4.0b3 even after i changed the safeGet() method to safe().

Comment: The latest version of Objectify is 4.0rc2 - you could try upgrading to see if this is just an objectify/appengine compatibility issue.

Comment: Did the upgrade to 4.0rc2 and still got the error, found out that i needed to upgrade manually the test libraries to resolve this error. Thanks to everyone who helped.